# Github Action Telegram Bot Workflow failing because of no access to secrets

Tags: github, github-actions, telegram-bot

If I run the workflow with the following markup (source: https://github.com/appleboy/telegram-action) it fails.

```
name: telegram message
on: [push]
jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: send telegram message on push
        uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
        with:
          to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TO }}
          token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          message: |
            ${{ github.actor }} created commit:
            Commit message: ${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}
            
            Repository: ${{ github.repository }}
            
            See changes: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/commit/${{github.sha}}
```

Even though I have set the secrets **TELEGRAM_TO** and **TELEGRAM_TOKEN** for the repository I see an error message in the Actions log:

`2023/03/03 23:54:12 missing telegram token or user list`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You must place:

```
build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    secrets: inherit # MUST HAVE THIS
    steps:
      - name: send telegram message on push
        uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
        with:
          to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TO }}
          token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          message: |
            ${{ github.actor }} created commit:
            Commit message: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
            
            Repository: ${{ github.repository }}
            
            See changes: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/commit/${{github.sha}}
```

it will inherit the secrets